# Retrofit2. Как получить код ответа при EOFException Gson парсера

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

Использую:

```
implementation group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'retrofit', version: '2.4.0'
implementation group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'adapter-rxjava2', version: '2.4.0'
implementation group: 'com.squareup.retrofit2', name: 'converter-gson', version: '2.4.0'
```

Есть запрос к API который возвращает `Observable<Response<List<String>>>`.

Если сервер возвращает валидный json, то я получаю желаемый объект. Если при запросе произошла ошибка, сервер ничего не возвращает и получаю ошибку `Caused by: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $`.

Можно ли как то получить `null` вместо `List<String>`?

Т.е. при правильно сформированном запросе я могу вернуть `List<String>`, но если пользователь не указал какие то данные, то я не могу сделать запрос в БД и вернуть результат. Т.е. это не ошибка сервера (5xx), это ошибка клиента (4xx).

Я хочу получить код ответа сервера, но из за того что "" не парсится в `List<String>` получаю `java.io.EOFException` и не могу узнать какая именно ошибка клиента(4xx) произошла. Так как вызывается `onError` при `subscribe`, а `Response<List<String>` попадает в `onNext`.

1) Я могу отдать пустой массив, но что делать с единичными объектами? Да и такой подход мне кажется неправильным. Если данные не получилось сформировать для ответа, то ничего и не нужно возвращать, только код ответа в заголовке.

2) Думал всегда принимать `Observable<Response<String>>` и парсить уже при получении (пустая строка да и любая другая пройдет). Я получу код ответа сервера и при удачном (201 прим.) буду парсить String. Но опять же, кажется крайне неудачным решением.

Comment: м.б отловить через try/catch и там выдернуть ошибку

Comment: @Романыч Observable<Response<List<String>>> при subscribe дергается два колбэка, один при удачном выполнении, другой при ошибке. Отказываться от RxJava не хочу, т.к. крайне удобно с ней работать. Должен быть способ решить задачу, я уверен :) но пока не знаю как. Т.е. try/catch сокрыты от меня, мне лишь возвращается throwable, да и все равно при таком подходе я получу только throwable, а нужен Response<Т>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так (ответ нашел на https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554, но пришлось немного изменить решение, т.к. что то в retrofit2 поменялось с 2016 года):

```
private class NullOnEmptyConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        final Converter<ResponseBody, ?> delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(this, type, annotations);

        return (Converter<ResponseBody, Object>) value -> {
            try {
                return delegate.convert(value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

после

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://your_url")
            .addConverterFactory(new NullOnEmptyConverterFactory())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Работает так:

```
AppService.INSTANCE.forDebug().subscribe(
            res -> {
                // Если Gson может распарсить ответ в List<String> - мы его получаем в res.body()
                // Если сервер вернет "" или "любые невалидные данные" - мы получаем null
                if (res.body() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                // Обработка res.code()

                // Логика приложения

            },  err -> {
                // Обработка ошибок, т.е. есил сюда попала ошибка, то это вина android разработчика
                // Все ошибки сервера 4хх или 5хх попадают в res
            }
    );
```

В результате удобные интерфейсы для вызова API

```
@GET("for_debug.php")
Observable<Response<List<String>>> forDebug();
```